# request-promise in node not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, promise

I am using [request-promise node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise). I have been following the docs, and believe I should have set everything up correctly, however, I am getting the following error:

> Unhandled rejection StatusCodeError: 400 - "{\n  \"error\" : {\n
>   \"status\" : 400,\n    \"message\" : \"invalid id\"\n  }\n}"
>       at new StatusCodeError (/Users/fitz035/Desktop/sony/travelLand/node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:32:15)

My code looks like the following.

```
var request = require('request');
var rp = require('request-promise');

rp('apiOne' + mood)
  .then(function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body)
    }
  }).then(function(error) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array; i++) {
      rp('apiTwo', function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body))
      });
    }
  }).then(function(error, response, body) {
    rp('apiThree' + songListUrl, function(error, response, body) {
      console.log(body))
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  });
```

**EDIT**

Is this the correct approach?

```
var options = {
    uri: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
    json: true
}

rp(options).then(function(data){
    console.log(data)
    var optionsTwo = {
        uri: 'http://www.google.com',
    }

    rp(optionsTwo).then(function(data){
        console.log(data)
        console.log(answer);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling `rp` as though it were `request` in a couple of places, such as in your `for` loop. Since you're not doing anything with the return value of those calls, you're not handling either resolution or rejection of those promises, thus getting the error warning you that there was a rejection you didn't handle.

The calls that you do use the return value from look incorrect as well. The callbacks you're passing in declare NodeJS-callback style argument lists, but that's not how promises work. Instead of a single callback that gets passed an error or `null` as the first argument, you register *separate* callbacks for resolution (success) and rejection (error).

I suggest studying the examples on [the `request-promise` page](https://github.com/request/request-promise) in detail.

---

Re your follow-up:

> Is this the correct approach?
>
> ```
> var options = {
>     uri: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
>     json: true
> }
>
> rp(options).then(function(data){
>     console.log(data)
>     var optionsTwo = {
>         uri: 'http://www.google.com',
>     }
>
>     rp(optionsTwo).then(function(data){
>         console.log(data)
>         console.log(answer);
>     })
> })
> ```

No, that still doesn't handle rejections. If your goal is to do those two requests in series (not in parallel), then see comments:

```
var options = {
    uri: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
    json: true
};

rp(options)
    .then(function(data){
        console.log(data)
        var optionsTwo = {
            uri: 'http://www.google.com'
        };

        return rp(optionsTwo).then(function(data){ // Note the return
            console.log(data)
            console.log(answer);                   // Don't know where `answer` is coming from...?
            // Note that by not returning anything, you convert
            // the resolution value to `undefined`. That's fine if
            // you don't need it, but it's worth pointing out.
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        // One of the two operations above failed
    });
```

Comment: i think my core understanding of how this works needs improvement. I was under the impression that the `then` function wouldn't trigger until the previous function had returned a response

Comment: @phantom: The callback you pass `then` won't be called until the promise is resolved or rejected, yes. More specifically: The callback you pass as the first argument to `then` will only be called when/if the promise is resolved; if you pass a second callback as a second argument, it won't get called until/unless the promise is rejected. The callback you pass as the only argument to `catch` is like the second argument to `then`: It's only called when/if the promise is rejected.

Comment: @tj I have updated my question. It appears to work. Could you confirm that this is the correct approach since you are the guru on here :-)?

Comment: @phantom: :-) I've added to the answer.